# jquery tablesorter and select all checkbox in table header

Tags: jquery, checkbox, tablesorter

I have a table with a "select all" checkbox as the first header column and some simple code to select all checkboxes on the page when the header checkbox is clicked.

```
$('#CheckAll').bind('click',function() {
        var checked = $(this).attr('checked');
        $('input').attr('checked', checked);
    });
```

the code runs fine, but as soon as I bind tablesorter to the table the click event on #CheckAll no longer seems to fire:

```
$('#ResultsTable').tablesorter( headers: { 0: { sorter: false} });
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's quite possible tablesorter is destroying/recreating the original Dom element. You can either bind AFTER your call to tablesorter, or else you might try "live" instead of "bind":

```
$('#CheckAll').live('click',function() {
        var checked = $(this).attr('checked');
        $('input').attr('checked', checked);
    });
```

Comment: nope - tried binding after, using live, as well as using live after the tablesorter() call, but event is still not getting fired.

Comment: nevermind - had a syntax error.  Works with binding the clickevent after the tablesorter call.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You almost got it!. Try this one:

```
 $("#tablesorter").tablesorter({headers:{0:{sorter:false}}});
```